# Toggle class of only the clicked div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-state

I need to toggle a class on each element, I tried this but it changes all of them at once

```
  const [mobileState, setMobileState] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setMobileState((prevMobileState) => !prevMobileState);
  };
```

```
myProjects.map((project) => (
              <div
                className={`work ${mobileState ? "active" : ""}`}
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
```

I tried using 'this' on the handleClick but typescript tells me that

> The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.

and gives me an error.

how should I proceed?

Comment: You need mobile state for each project, so treat mobileState as an array, rather than a single value.

Comment: I hope the linked post will help you. Else, you can reply here.